# Isolating string data SQLite using substr, instr, and trim functions

Tags: sqlite

How do I isolate the latitude and longitude coordinates from the following string of data.  I have tried several combinations of substr, instr, and trim, but have had no success.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
{"latitude":31.3495768,"longitude":-109.5176988,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3495769,"longitude":-109.5176986,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.349555,"longitude":-109.5176636,"accuracy":55.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}   
{"latitude":31.3495556,"longitude":-109.5176675,"accuracy":55.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3495556,"longitude":-109.5176675,"accuracy":55.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3495768,"longitude":-109.5176988,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.349577,"longitude":-109.5176988,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}   
{"latitude":31.349577,"longitude":-109.5176988,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}   
{"latitude":31.3495545,"longitude":-109.5176644,"accuracy":55.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3091678,"longitude":-109.5241938,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3091684,"longitude":-109.5241915,"accuracy":46.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3091677,"longitude":-109.524194,"accuracy":24.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}   
{"latitude":31.3091677,"longitude":-109.5241939,"accuracy":24.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3091676,"longitude":-109.5241938,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":33.415518729047,"longitude":-111.93584326665,"accuracy":100.0}                                 
{"latitude":31.3495769,"longitude":-109.5176986,"accuracy":25.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3412066,"longitude":-109.5530025,"accuracy":50.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}  
{"latitude":31.3411891,"longitude":-109.5530071,"accuracy":51.0,"altitude":0.0,"heading":0.0,"speed":0.0}
```

Comment: This is the best statement that still works, but is no where close to the desired output.         SELECT substr(messages.coordinates, 13, 20) AS Latitude FROM messages WHERE messages.coordinates IS NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

The column `coordinates` contains values that are well-formed JSONs, so you can use [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex) function:

```
SELECT json_extract(coordinates, '$.latitude') Latitude,
       json_extract(coordinates, '$.longitude') Longtitude
FROM messages 
WHERE coordinates IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4ad916f3b2e4e03502d47f4d2130162f).

Comment: @MAG fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.